# How do i get authorisation from google-apps-script so I dont get this: "Exception: You do not have permission to call MailApp.sendEmail"?

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I get the authorisation to let the script send emails with MailApp.sendEmail from my email?
I dont know a lot about that stuff so please dont use complicated terms in your answer. Thank you in advance :)

I tried to send an email to everyone that participated in a question and I know that google should normally ask for authorisation before it can send emails but how do i trigger that?

Comment: Execute the function from the file project

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: You have a RUN button on top of Apps Script IDE. It will trigger authorization.